# Is there a performance difference between using HTML attributes/tags compared to inline styles?

Tags: html, css, performance

Consider the following two snippets of markup:

```
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 10pt">
    Blah blah blah
</p>
```

Versus this:

```
<p align="center">
    <small>
        Blah blah blah
    </small>
</p>
```

Now, performance optimisation tools often recommend that inline styles should be avoided, so would the second, attribute-based option, be better in this case?

Comment: To be clear - I'm interested in the performance difference between HTML tags and attributes vs inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think neither situation is good. You should avoid using inline styles. Maybe the css used in the external file is correct, use class to change the label style.

```html
<p class="paragraph">
    Blah blah blah
</p>
```

And in css

```css
.paragraph {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this? Why should one avoid inline styles (is it possible that some systems like some email clients may require them?) and why should one avoid using the HTML tag small? The question was about efficiency of processing and it would be good to understand why your solution is better in this regard since it requires an extra HTTP request (to fetch the CSS file).

Comment: When your page has a lot of inline styles, or <small> tags, or there are multiple html pages, it is difficult to use inline styles or <small> to change the style as a whole.
When you use an external css file, one css file can be used in multiple html pages. When you change a class style, you only need to change one line of code, and inline-style should change many lines of code. The html file describes the basic structure, and the css file changes the style. So we often use external css files to set styles.

Comment: Don't worry to use an extra HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a difference, when you use separate separate CSS file, it takes another request and then parsing to actually paint the template. But if you style html directly it will be direct parsing without additional request. The biggest issue here is that code must be easily readable and html with all the styles implemented in it looks like a total mess. After all the list of attributes that need to be styled can be very long, not to even talk about pseudo elements and their styles. What CSS file provides is organisation, it separates two different kinds of code and that makes it way more readable and understandable. In that particular case which you posted it wouldn't make any difference as you can't event notice It, but in general I strongly recommend to separate CSS code.